# How do I check for values or partical within an array using an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure how I can do a partial match base on input given by user. Cross check that value `inside` the input within the `array` for any partial matches, then add a class `display`

For example if I type inside the inputbox the following:

> Build Web Application John James

It will fetch all the values inside for any partial matches inside the array. Then loop through all the `name` classes to add a class called `display`. If there isn't a single match it will then remove the class `display`

```js
$(".task-label input").on("change keyup paste", function(){
        let handles = ['john', 'jake', 'james'];

             
        for(let elements of handles ) {

  
            if (elements.includes($('.task-label input').value())) {
                $('.name-'+ elements).addClass();
              } else {
                console.log('no match');
            }

  
          }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="task-label">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
      </div>
      
      <ul class="name-list">
        <li id="john" class="name name-john">@John</li>
        <li id="jake" class="name name-jake">@Jake</li>
        <li id="alex" class="name name-alex">@Alex</li>
        <li id="allison" class="name name-allison">@Allison</li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i was you this is how i would do this.

First i would change the classes in the list to data-attributes.
This makes it much cleaner and easier to search.

Note: this does not take into account Uppercase/Lowercase. You need to implement a little more code for that to work.

The code is commented and if you have questions please ask.

```js
$(".task-label input").on("change keyup paste", function() {
  
  // check for special characters
  var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
  
  // get input and convert to array
  var searchFor = $(this).val().split(" ");
  
  // clear the display class before a new search to reset
  $(".name-list").find('li').removeClass("display");
  
  // search the list from the elements in the array
  for(var el of searchFor){
  
    var name = "[data-name*="+el+"]";
    
    // make sure not empty or special char before finding the name
    if(el.match(letters)){
      $(".name-list").find(name).addClass("display");
    }
    
  }
  
});
```

```css
.display {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="name-list">
  <li id="john" class="name" data-name="john">@John</li>
  <li id="jake" class="name" data-name="jake">@Jake</li>
  <li id="alex" class="name" data-name="alex">@Alex</li>
  <li id="allison" class="name" data-name="allison">@Allison</li>
</ul>

<div class="task-label">
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to check for a partial match. I have to complete the whole string in order for it to add a class. Lets say I type in just `jo`, it will search the list for strings or data-attribute containing just `jo` instead of completing the whole string `john`. Since you are using an `if` statement. It will check an exact match before adding the class

Comment: yes, I have added a * in the find data-name. Though it is still case sensitive.

Comment: Didn't know about that, now I just need to add a condition to remove the `display` class if there isn't any matches (partial or exact)

Comment: it should do that already. it clears all display class on each keydown then reapplies them based on the search.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-name*=@]` if started the text or with an `@` character or any kind of special character. Is there a way to allow it to accept special characters?

Comment: Yeap, here you go, I have added a match before searching to take ignore special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right with your solution you just need changing this part `elements.includes($('.task-label input').val())` to `$('.task-label input').val().includes(elements)` because if those pre defined names exist anywhere in the user input then you would add the class. Hope this helps..

Comment: Is there a way to check for a partial match? It seems I need to complete the whole string. Lets say If I just type `jo` it will search all the values inside the array that has `jo` inside.

Comment: Yes sure you can do that also. You can then keep both the conditions one which you added earlier and also the condition which i had modifed to and keep both the conditions in an `or` expression then it should work both ways.

Comment: I can't seem to figure how I can obtain a partial match only

Comment: You have to use both `elements.includes($('.task-label input').val()) ` and `$('.task-label input').val().includes(elements)` in an `OR` expression so that you can check if the single names in your pre defined list of names exist some where in user input as well as if the whole user input partially matches with any of the pre defined names. Can you post your modified code?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the jquery function to get the text input's value is val(), not value(). Anyways you need not to use jquery to get it's value. Just refer to "this.value" inside the handler. The following implementation checks for the partial matches and it's case insensitive too.

```
$(".task-label input").on("change keyup paste", function(){
  let handles = ['john', 'jake', 'james'];
  for(let elements of handles ) {         
     if (elements.includes(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
        console.log("matched with " + elements);
        $('.name-'+ elements).addClass();
     }else {
        console.log("no-match");
     }         
  }  
})
```